# How and when to use the getline function to perform calculations?

Tags: c++, getline

I am taking a course on C++ and I have been asked to compute the area of a circle by using `getline`. I was advised to refrain from using  `cin` unless it is really necessary.

Below is my code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string question ("Enter the radius: ");
    std::string s_radius;
    std::cout << question;

    getline(std::cin, s_radius);

    const double PI = 3.14159;
    double n_radius = std::stod(s_radius);
    double area = PI * n_radius * n_radius;

    std::cout << "The area of the circle = " << area << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is it really necessary to go through the process of accepting a string as input and convert it to a numeral to perform the calculation?

Comment: how you get the input and the calculations you do with the input are orthogonal concerns. Using `cin` is often easier, sometimes its easier to use `getline`, depends on the format of the input. However, "refrain from using cin unless it is really necessary" I never heard before

Comment: @Carcigenicate you can ignore errors whether you use `std::cin >>` or `getline`, that doesnt really make them different

Comment: There must have been some misunderstanding somewhere - you're still using `std::cin`. (It's not easy to read from standard input without using `std::cin`.) If the requirement is that you read the input with `getline`, there is no way to get around the conversion.

Comment: On a tangent: a *numeral* is a symbol - that is, a string of some kind - and not a number. "12" and "XII" are numerals that both represent the number twelve. Literal numerical values, like `3.14159` and `0`, are numerals. The values of `PI` and `n_radius`, on the other hand, are not.

Comment: typically to avoid pitfalls like this : [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: If you don't want to use std::string then you can simply go with std::cin. In your case, you're already advised to use getline. getline actually get line from stream into string until the delimitation character ('\n') is found, so you have to use string to store the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it really necessary to go through the process of accepting a string as input and convert it to a numeral to perform the calculation?

It isn't strictly necessary but it does enforce good habits.  Let's assume you are going to ask for 2 numbers from the users and use something like

```
std::cout << "Enter first number: ";
std::cin >> first_number;
std::cout << "Enter second number: ";
std::cin >> second_number;
```

For the first number the user enters `123bob`.  `operator>>` is going to start reading it in and once it hits `b` it is going to stop and store `123` into `first_number`.  Now the stream has `bob` still in it.  When it asks for the second number since `bob` is still in the stream it will fail and `second_number` will get set to `0`.  Then the program will continue on and you will get garbage output because you accepted garbage input.

Now, if you read in as a `std:string` and then convert to what you want it makes it easier to catch these types of errors.  `getline(std::cin, some_string);` would get all of `123bob` out of the input buffer so you don't have to worry about having to clean it up.  Then using `stoi` (or any of the `stox` functions) it will read the valid value of of it.  The functions also have a second parameter which is a pointer to a `size_t` and if you pass it one it will store the position of the first unconverted character in the string and you can use that to tell if the entire input string is valid or not.  So, if you had

```
std::string input;
std::cout << "Enter some number: ";
std::getline(std::cin, input);
std::size_t pos;
double number = std::stod(input, &pos);
if (pos == input.size())
    std::cout << "valid input\n";
else
    std::cout << "invalid input\n";
```

Then `1.23bob` would cause `invalid input` to print where `1.23` cause `valid input` to print.  You could even use this in a loop to make sure you get only valid input like

```
double number;
do
{   
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Enter some number: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::size_t pos;
    number = std::stod(input, &pos);
    if (pos != input.size())
        std::cout << "invalid input\n";
    else
        break;
} while(true)
```

---

TL;DR: If you rely on the user to only input valid input eventually you are going to get burned. Reading in as a string and converting offers a consistent way to ensure that you are only getting good input from your user.

Answer (score 0):

> I was advised to refrain from using cin unless it is really necessary.

First of all, there is a misunderstanding, because you are still using `std::cin`. I will interpret your question as using `std::cin::operator >>` vs `getline(std::cin,...)`. Next I would rather suggest you the opposite: Use `operator>>` directly if you can and fall back to `getline` if you have to.

**A very contrived example:**

Imagine you have integers stored in a file in this (unnecessarily complex) format,

```
3123212
^-------- number of digits of the first number
 ^^^----- first number
    ^---- number of digits of the second number
     ^^-- second number
```

You cannot use a bare `std::cin >>` to read those numbers. Instead you need to read the whole line and then parse the numbers. However, even for this I would highly recommend to provide an overload for `operator>>`, something along the line of

```
struct NumbersReadFromStrangeFormat {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
};

std::isstream& operator>>(std::istream& in,NumbersReadFromStrangeFormat& num) {
    // use getline and parse the numbers from the string
    return in;
}
```

Such that you can again write:

```
NumbersReadFromStrangeFormat numbers;
std::cin >> numbers;
```

**Conclusion:**
Overloading the `operator>>` is the idomatic way to read something from an input stream. "Using `std::cin`" or "using `getline`" are not really alternatives. "Refraining from using `std::cin`" must be a misunderstanding. If there is no overload of `operator>>` that already does what you need, you can write your own and nicely hide any `getline` or other parsing details.